Copy a button from another tab
I've got part of a macro currently that runs when you click a button on Tab A.
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 36")).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

It copies Button 36 and pastes it below the button you clicked.
I now need to copy this tab and ideally not alter the macro, however when I copy the tab, button 36 has it's ID number changed. When this macro runs on the new tab, there is no Button 36 on the active sheet for it to copy.
I tried altering the code and setting up a new tab for the button to live, and have it always copying from that tab. But it didn't work. It's not something silly like needing to switch back to the correct sheet right? Does Worksheets() make the selected sheet active?
Worksheets("Buttons").Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks!

Try Worksheets("Buttons").Shapes("Button 1").Copy  You can't Select something on a sheet that's not Active, but luckily you can copy it without needing to select it...

Wouldn't it be easier to add a new button via code though, instead of copying another one?  It might help to explain a little around what you're trying to implement using your code.

@TimWilliams thanks for the thoughts - I'll explore both of these options! I assume when creating a button with VBA you can assign a macro to it. Will have a geez shortly.


Add a command button (Form Control) with Buttons.Add method
Assign macro with OnAction property

Option Explicit

' -- Standard Module
Sub Btn_Click()
    MsgBox "Bingo"
End Sub

Sub AddBtn()
    Dim oBtn As Object
    Set oBtn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(50, 50, 70, 30)
    oBtn.Caption = "NewBtn"
    oBtn.OnAction = "Btn_Click"
End Sub

